# cannot use the 'machineformat' input argument on calling loadMNISTImages function from simulink

Tags: image, matlab, conv-neural-network, simulink, stateflow

I am calling the simple CNN which classifies the MNIST images. The CNN internally calls loadMNISTImages() functions to read images from a file. When this CNN is connected to my simulink model.

I am getting the following error:

> For code generation, you cannot use the 'machineformat' input
>   argument. Function 'loadMNISTImages.m' (#77.233.262), line 8, column
>   9: "fread(fp, 1, 'int32', 0, 'b')" Launch diagnostic report.

### This is the function which reads the MNIST images:

```
 function images = loadMNISTImages(filename)

 %loadMNISTImages returns a 28x28x[number of MNIST images] matrix 
 %containing the raw MNIST images

 fp = fopen(filename, 'rb');
 assert(fp ~= -1, ['Could not open ', filename, '']);

 magic = fread(fp, 1, 'int32', 0, 'b');
 assert(magic == 2051, ['Bad magic number in ', filename, '']);

 numImages = fread(fp, 1, 'int32', 0, 'ieee-be');
 numRows = fread(fp, 1, 'int32', 0, 'ieee-be');
 numCols = fread(fp, 1, 'int32', 0, 'ieee-be');

 images = fread(fp, inf, 'unsigned char=>unsigned char');
 images = reshape(images, numCols, numRows, numImages);
 images = permute(images,[2 1 3]);

 fclose(fp);

 % Reshape to #pixels x #examples
 images = reshape(images, size(images, 1) * size(images, 2), size(images, 3));
 % Convert to double and rescale to [0,1]
 images = double(images) / 255;

 end
```

---

### The above function is called from a function TestMNISTCONV

```
 function y2 = TestMnistConv()

 Images = 
 loadMNISTImages('C:\Users\surinder\Downloads\experiments\cnn\MNIST\t10k-images.idx3-ubyte');
 Images = reshape(Images, 28, 28, []);
 Labels = 
 loadMNISTLabels('C:\Users\surinder\Downloads\experiments\cnn\MNIST\t10k- 
 labels.idx1-ubyte');
 Labels(Labels == 0) = 10;    % 0 --> 10
```

---

Finally i am calling this function from a state in Stateflow chart and hence getting this error. Please can anyone help ?:)

Answer (score 0):

Any function that cannot be converted to equivalent C code needs to be defined as [coder.extrinsic](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.extrinsic.html)

In your case  you need to use `coder.extrinsic('loadMNISTImages');`.

You will also likely have problems related to the size of your variables.  Simulink/Stateflow will almost certainly not allow you to change the dimension of `Images` on the fly -  you will probably need to move the `reshape` into `loadMNISTImages`, and you will need to predefine the size of `Images` and `Labels` using something like

`Images = zeros(28,28,...);`

Comment: I tried this, now the compile is clean but the simulation doesnot run , Simulink Dialog box prints the message 'starting' and it simply comes out. Do i need to do something more ?